# How do i acces individual Values in a hash table

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have an assignment where i have to take an string input and apply zipfs law to it. Im having issues accessing the value in a hashtable. Whenever i find a word that already exist i'm supposed to update the wordcounter +1. What ends up happening is the counter applies to all the values in the hash table, and i get ridiculously high numbers. I cant wrap my head around how i'm supposed to give an individual counter for each keyvalue

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Spire.Doc;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Zipf
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Hashtable wordRegister;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] ArrLoop = TextSplitter();
            int[] wordCount = new int[ArrLoop.Length];
            int count = 1;
            wordRegister = new Hashtable();


            for(int i = 0; i < ArrLoop.Length; i++)
            {
                if (wordRegister.ContainsKey(ArrLoop[i]))
                {
                    // here is where im having trouble
                    wordRegister[ArrLoop[i]] = count += 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    wordRegister.Add(ArrLoop[i], count);
                }



            }
            foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in wordRegister)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key : {pair.Key} ; Forekomster : {pair.Value}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        public static String WordString()
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\2.g\IDO.docx");

            String textString = doc.GetText();

            return textString;

         }

        public static string[] TextSplitter()
        {
            string s = WordString();
            String[] wordArr = s.Split();

            return wordArr;
        }




}
```

}

Comment: You should first be able to answer the question “what is a hash table and why is it useful?” If you can get this right, you’ll probably have a better idea wheat is going on with your code.

Comment: Side note, it might be easier to use a Dictionary than a hashtable.

Comment: Votung to close as "to broad" as this needs to be explained person due to the number of misunderstanding of programming the question shows.   (maybe ofter a top student at your university a coffee)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the count variable. You are incrementing a counter common to all entries.

Try this instead to keep the counts distinct from each other:

wordRegister[ArrLoop[i]] += 1;